# num_states = len(self.cell.state_size) TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int32' has no len() when using CuDNNGRU

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I used the CuDNNGRU to implement the GRU, and the code is shown as below. And it gave me this error as shown below. I have searched online and found someone ran into similar problems but I didn't find any solutions. I am not sure if it's a bug or a implementation problem. However, the same code work fine with CuDNNLSTM. I just can't figure out where the problem is.

```
  def build_model_GRU(timesteps, features, units, dropout_rate, learning_rate):
    inputs1 = Input(shape=(timesteps, features[0]))
    lstm1 = CuDNNGRU(units,  stateful=False, return_sequences=True)(inputs1)
    drop_layer1 = Dropout(dropout_rate)(lstm1)
    dense_1 = Dense(units, activation='relu')(drop_layer1)
    average_pooling1 = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(dense_1)

    inputs2 = Input(shape=(timesteps, features[1]))
    lstm2 = CuDNNGRU(units,  stateful=False, return_sequences=True)(inputs2)
    drop_layer2 = Dropout(dropout_rate)(lstm2)
    dense_2 = Dense(units, activation='relu')(drop_layer2)
    average_pooling2 = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(dense_2)

    inputs3 = Input(shape=(timesteps, features[2]))
    lstm3 = CuDNNGRU(units,  stateful=False, return_sequences=True)(inputs3)
    drop_layer3 = Dropout(dropout_rate)(lstm3)
    dense_3 = Dense(units, activation='relu')(drop_layer3)
    average_pooling3 = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(dense_3)

    merged = concatenate([average_pooling1, average_pooling2, average_pooling3])
    dense_all = Dense(10, activation='relu')(merged)
    output = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(dense_all)
    model = Model(inputs=[inputs1, inputs2, inputs3], outputs=output)
    opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate, decay=1e-5)
    model.compile(loss=[focal_loss(alpha=0.25, gamma=2)], optimizer=opt,
                  metrics=['acc'])
    return model

n_timesteps=100
n_features=np.array([10,40,80])
n_units=32
dropout_rate=0.5
learning_rate=0.00001
model = build_model_GRU(timesteps=n_timesteps, features=n_features, units=n_units, dropout_rate=dropout_rate, learning_rate=learning_rate)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\zz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
>   line 3267, in run_code
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)   File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('E:/projects/all_process_longleaf_GRU.py', wdir='E:/projects')   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm
>   2019.2.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
>       pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm
>   2019.2.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev_pydev_imps_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
>       exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)   File "E:/projects/all_process_longleaf_GRU.py", line 409, in 
>       main()   File "E:/projects/all_process_longleaf_GRU.py", line 346, in main
>       train_model(new_train_data, y_train, new_vali_data, y_vali, result_path_1st, hidden_nodes[j])   File
>   "E:/projects/all_process_longleaf_GRU.py", line 206, in
>   train_model
>       dropout_rate=dropout_rate, learning_rate=learning_rate)   File "E:/projects/all_process_longleaf_GRU.py", line 143, in
>   build_model_GRU
>       lstm1 = CuDNNGRU(units,  stateful=False, return_sequences=True)(inputs1)   File
>   "C:\Users\zz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py",
>   line 541, in **call**
>       return super(RNN, self).**call**(inputs, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\zz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py",
>   line 489, in **call**
>       output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\zz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\cudnn_recurrent.py",
>   line 81, in call
>       if len(initial_state) != len(self.states):   File "C:\Users\zz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py",
>   line 438, in states
>       num_states = len(self.cell.state_size) TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int32' has no len()

Comment: It's a small thing, but the title says _type 'numpy.int64'_, whereas the error message contains _type 'numpy.int32'_. Is there a typo?

Comment: I have changed the title. It's a typo. So any suggestions?